# Is there native .NET type for CIDR subnets?

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, subnet, cidr

It's simple enough to code up a class to store/validate something like `192.168.0.0/16`, but I was curious if a native type for this already existed in .NET?  I would imagine it would work a lot like `IPAddress`:

```
CIDR subnet = CIDR.Parse("192.168.0.0/16");
```

Basically it just needs to make sure you're working with an IPv4 or IPv6 address and then that the number of bits your specifying is valid for that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is such native type in .NET, you will need to develop one your self.

Answer (score 30):

You can use the code from GitHub to do just that:

https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork

```
IPNetwork ipnetwork = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.168.100/24");

Console.WriteLine("Network : {0}", ipnetwork.Network);
Console.WriteLine("Netmask : {0}", ipnetwork.Netmask);
Console.WriteLine("Broadcast : {0}", ipnetwork.Broadcast);
Console.WriteLine("FirstUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.FirstUsable);
Console.WriteLine("LastUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.LastUsable);
Console.WriteLine("Usable : {0}", ipnetwork.Usable);
Console.WriteLine("Cidr : {0}", ipnetwork.Cidr);
```

Output

```
Network : 192.168.168.0
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
Broadcast : 192.168.168.255
FirstUsable : 192.168.168.1
LastUsable : 192.168.168.254
Usable : 254
Cidr : 24
```

Answer (score 12):

For ASP.NET Core there is now [IPNetwork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.httpoverrides.ipnetwork) class.  Example usage below:

```
var addr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.0");
var mask = 16;
var test = new IPNetwork(addr, mask).Contains(context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
```

Answer (score 4):

[IPNetwork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipnetwork) is now available in the System.Net namespace starting with .NET 8.

```cs
IPNetwork n = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.0.0/16");
```