# How to calculate a IPv6 CIDR route prefix in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, network-programming, ipv6

I've been working on generating a CIDR from ranges of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses using T-SQL running on a SQL Server 2012 instance. Generally our application (outside of the db) is responsible for calculating a CIDR, but I presently have need to do the CIDR calculation in the database. Because IPv6 is too large to store in the `bigint` datatype we store IP addresses as either `binary(4)` or `binary(16)`.

Calculating the route prefix for an IPv4 range is relatively simple if a little ugly:

```
declare @ipv4_begin binary(4)
       ,@ipv4_end binary(4)

set @ipv4_begin = 0xC0A80000 -- '192.168.000.000'
set @ipv4_end = 0xC0A8FFFF   -- '192.168.255.255'

select 32 - LOG(
                Cast(@ipv4_end As bigint)
                - Cast(@ipv4_begin As bigint) + 1, 2
               ) as ipv4_route_prefix
```

Sadly the same query modified for IPv6 does not work. The reason it does not work is because IPv6 addressees are larger than what can be stored in the `bigint` datatype (the reason we use `binary(4)` and `binary(16)` for storage):

```
declare @ipv6_begin binary(16)
       ,@ipv6_end binary(16)

set @ipv6_begin = 0xFC000000000000000000000000000000 -- fc00:: 
set @ipv6_end = 0xFC00000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   -- fc00::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

-- This will cause error: 'An invalid floating point operation occurred.'
select 128 - LOG(
                 Cast(@ipv6_end As bigint)
                 - Cast(@ipv6_begin As bigint) + 1, 2
                ) as ipv6_route_prefix
```

Aside from wonky bitwise operations (that ultimately didn't work) I haven't come up anything that will do this calculation in the database.

Can a route prefix for an IPv6 CIDR be calculated from an IPv6 address range in T-SQL?

Comment: While the above examples are simple select statements, I am totally open to SQL server functions, common table expressions, bitwise operations, or any other solution that works.

Comment: Maybe you can check some C# solutions (http://ipnetwork.codeplex.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/310599/1080354) and try to implement them in SQL Server using CLR function?

Comment: @gotqn I am utilizing a shared DB server instance. Because of this my DBAs are hesitant (rightfully so) to add CLR types. That said the [IPNetwork Utility](http://ipnetwork.codeplex.com/) while helpful (I've used it before) doesn't support IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you already have a neat trick for IPv4 -- just chop the value up into the biggest chunk we can handle and repeat the trick.

```
SELECT ISNULL(MIN(32 - B + N), 128) 
FROM (VALUES
    (LOG(
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    1, 4)) - 
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  1, 4)
        ) + 1, 2),  0),
    (LOG(
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    5, 4)) - 
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  5, 4)
        ) + 1, 2), 32),
    (LOG(
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    9, 4)) - 
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  9, 4)
        ) + 1, 2), 64),
    (LOG(
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,   13, 4)) - 
        CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin, 13, 4)
        ) + 1, 2), 96)
) AS Bits(B, N)
WHERE B <> 0;
```

We determine the position of the first set bit in each chunk, then pick the lowest such bit -- if there is no such bit, all bits match (the `ISNULL` covers that case). This works for IPv4 too if you replace the "128" with "32", though obviously you already have an expression for that. We can pack it up in a function that will work for both:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CidrPrefixFromRange(@ip_begin VARBINARY(16), @ip_end VARBINARY(16)) 
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT ISNULL(MIN(32 - B + N), DATALENGTH(@ip_begin) * 8) AS Prefix
    FROM (VALUES
        (LOG(
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    1, 4)) - 
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  1, 4)
            ) + 1, 2),  0),
        (LOG(
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    5, 4)) - 
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  5, 4)
            ) + 1, 2), 32),
        (LOG(
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,    9, 4)) - 
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin,  9, 4)
            ) + 1, 2), 64),
        (LOG(
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_end,   13, 4)) - 
            CONVERT(BIGINT, SUBSTRING(@ip_begin, 13, 4)
            ) + 1, 2), 96)
    ) AS Bits(B, N)
    WHERE B <> 0;
```

Sample uses:

```
-- 192.168.100.0 - 192.168.103.255
SELECT * FROM dbo.CidrPrefixFromRange(0xc0a86400, 0xc0a867ff) -- /22

-- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
SELECT * FROM dbo.CidrPrefixFromRange(0xC0A80000, 0xC0A8FFFF) -- /16

-- fc00:: - fc00::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
SELECT * FROM dbo.CidrPrefixFromRange(
    0xFC000000000000000000000000000000,
    0xFC00000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
) -- /64

-- 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1
SELECT * FROM dbo.CidrPrefixFromRange(0x7f000001, 0x7f000001) -- /32
```

No promises as to how efficient this is... if you want efficiency, this is not the sort of thing you want to do in T-SQL. :-)

*Addendum*: the reason I use a table-valued function and not a simpler scalar-valued function (after all, we're only returning one value) is that scalar-valued functions [perform far worse inside a query](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273443/). An inline table-valued function can be efficiently `CROSS APPLY`'d to a table. For that reason I write every function as an inline TVF as a matter of habit even if I don't foresee such a use -- anything is better than a scalar-valued function.

Comment: It fails with values such as 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 - 0x01000000000000000000000000000000 which I believe should return a 8. ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b809/3 ) a ceiling may fix this, but I have to run it through the paces once I get in front of something more sophisticated than a SQL fiddle

Comment: @rheone: I'm assuming the end ranges all end in 1-bits, because otherwise there is no prefix. In your example, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 - 0x00ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff. Otherwise, yes, you'll get rounding issues as we're no longer dealing with integer powers of 2. Making the function deal with erroneous input requires a little more work than `CEILING`, but it could be done.

Comment: I have an alternate implementation that chops the input up in bytes and uses `XOR`, incidentally -- that always returns integral results, but it still won't give the *correct* result if your range can't be described by a prefix. (Also, it's not as obvious.)

Comment: you absolutely right. I was miss remembering the problem that ahsteele were working on. the high address would always only follow the pattern of 2^(n)-1 padded to 128 bits (0, 1, 3, 7, f followed by f's if encoded in hex). As an asside an XOR operation between the high and the low would result in a bitmask. This bitmask could be ORed with the high and again inversed and ANDed with the low to correct wrong high/low address that wouldn't fit a proper cidr formatting, that I described above. But this should not be necessary in our case as the inputs are clean.

Comment: Nice job, sometimes it is the easiest solution which is the best *and* most elusive.