# Map list of IPs to list of subnets (cidr)

Tags: powershell, subnet

I have list over 3k IPs which I need to map to correct subnets (cidr). I already created basic PS script but in some cases IP is map to two or more subnets, what is incorrect.

Looks like it is working only for subnets with mask /24 and when I have lower mask then it is mapping two subnets as in example below

```
abc         10.41.92.45     

Map too

10.41.92.0/29   sub1
10.41.92.40/29  sub2
```

Anyone could help with below

```
$SimpleSitelist = @(Import-csv -path C:\Users\ip\subnet.csv  )

#Site,CIDR
#Site1,192.168.1.0/24
#Site2,192.168.2.0/24
 
$SimpleHostList = @(Import-Csv -path C:\Users\ip.csv )

#hostname,ipaddress
#host1, 192.168.2.45
#host2, 192.168.1.45

foreach ($SingleHost in $SimpleHostList){
    $first, $second, $thrid, $4th = $SingleHost.IPAddress.split('.')
    $Sitetest = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $first, $second, $thrid
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Hostname  = $SingleHost.Hostname
        IPAddress = $SingleHost.IPAddress
        Site      = ($SimpleSitelist | where CIDR -match $Sitetest).Site
        Subnet      = ($SimpleSitelist | where CIDR -match $Sitetest).CIDR
        }
    }
```

example of data

```
abc;10.41.92.45
xyz;10.188.2.48
abc1;10.248.232.5
aabb;151.156.179.145
         
sub1;10.41.92.0/29
sub2;10.41.92.40/29
sub3;10.188.2.0/24
sub4;10.248.232.0/21    
sub5;151.156.179.0/24
```

Thanks for support

Comment: Your code will only work properly with /24 ranges, because each /24 range has distinct values in the first 3 octet and that’s what you’re testing against for IP address membership of the range. The problem is CIDR ranges can be more granular - the range “10.41.92.40/29” runs from “10.41.92.40” to “10.41.92.47” so an address like “10.41.92.100” *isn’t* in the range “10.41.92.40/29” but your code says it is because it’s just looking for a “10.41.92” prefix.

Comment: How I can edit code to work for any mask?

Comment: Pseudo-code: (i) calculate the start and end address of the cidr range and convert them to uint32 (ii) convert the ip address to uint32 and see if it falls between the start and end values (inclusive). Implementation left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Someone probably made a module for this.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently dotnet core has a [`System.Net.IPNetwork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipnetwork?view=net-8.0) struct that makes this a lot easier than having to twiddle bits inside a Uint32.

We can set up your sample data like this:

```
$sites = @"
sub1;10.41.92.0/29
sub2;10.41.92.40/29
sub3;10.188.2.0/24
sub4;10.248.232.0/21    
sub5;151.156.179.0/24
"@ | convertfrom-csv -header @( "Name", "CIDR" ) -delimiter ";";

$hosts = @"
bc;10.41.92.45
xyz;10.188.2.48
abc1;10.248.232.5
aabb;151.156.179.145
"@ | convertfrom-csv -header @("Hostname", "IPAddress") -delimiter ";";
```

Then parse the CIDR ranges into `IPNetwork` structs:

```
# parse the cidr range text string for each site
$networks = $sites | foreach-object {
    $parts = $_.CIDR.Split("/");
    $network = new-object System.Net.IPNetwork(
        [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($parts[0]),
        [int]::Parse($parts[1])
    );
    [pscustomobject] @{
        "Site"    = $_
        "Network" = $network
    }
}
```

And finally check each host for membership of networks:

```
$membership = foreach( $hostinfo in $hosts )
{
    $hostIpAddress = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($hostinfo.IPAddress);
    $hostNetworks  = $networks | where-object { $_.Network.Contains($hostIpAddress) };
    [pscustomobject]@{
         "Hostname"  = $hostinfo.Hostname
         "IPAddress" = $hostinfo.IPAddress
         "Site"      = $hostNetworks.Site
         "Subnet"    = $hostNetworks.Site.CIDR
    }            
}

$membership
```

which outputs:

```
Hostname IPAddress       Site                                Subnet
-------- ---------       ----                                ------
bc       10.41.92.45     @{Name=sub2; CIDR=10.41.92.40/29}   10.41.92.40/29
xyz      10.188.2.48     @{Name=sub3; CIDR=10.188.2.0/24}    10.188.2.0/24
abc1     10.248.232.5    @{Name=sub4; CIDR=10.248.232.0/21 } 10.248.232.0/21
aabb     151.156.179.145 @{Name=sub5; CIDR=151.156.179.0/24} 151.156.179.0/24
```

Credit to this answer for pointing the way...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63161497/3156906

Comment: Nice.  Note Powershell 7 only has [System.Net.IPNetwork].